# How to create login and user registration without database

Tags: sql, database, local-storage, indexeddb

I need to do a login and user registration form without using a database. The ideia is getting it working just like a normal website login/registration form, but it only has to work locally (in my computer, without web). So what's the better way to do this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please Try using CSV or excel file
where one column can store the username and the other can store password

Answer (score 0):

You could create a file settings, where you set your users and passwords. 
Login form would work normally, into backend you have to ask to your settings files instead of database.